# How to set up SSIS to extract data from Postgres Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, ssis, etl

I have a database PostGres database in the AWS Cloud. I would like to use SSIS to extract tables and move them over to a local SQL Server.
Has anyone attempted to do this? Is it possible?

Ultimately I would like to move over tables from the PostGres to a SQL server, without having to purchase a tool.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-postgresql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017), you would need to follow these steps to connect SSIS to a Postgres database:

- get the PostgreSQL ODBC driver, either with Stack Builder or using ODBC
- connect to PostgreSQL with the PostgreSQL ODBC driver (psqlODBC), using the proper connection string, typically `Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};Server=<server>;Port=<port>;Database=<database>;UID=<user id>;PWD=<password>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Postgres OLE DB Provider](https://www.pgoledb.com) to connect to Postgres using OLE DB Source. The following link contains a step by step guide to import data from Postgres into SQL Server:

- [Export data from Postgres to SQL Server using SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2619/export-data-from-postgres-to-sql-server-using-ssis/)